# Using of and for responsibly

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

```
The medium of instruction for the entire course is English
```

I am confused if the sentence above is grammatically correct or not.

Thanks.

Comment: What is it you're confused about? Whether the teacher will be using English to teach, or if you will learn English in this class, or something else? I know you don't know and that's why you're asking, but can you at least specify the extent of what you don't know? I'm guessing that sentence doesn't cause confusion about individual words like English, medium, instruction, otherwise you would have asked about them.

Comment: *In principle*, either preposition *(**of, for**)* could be used in either or both positions. But on balance, the choice you've made (or copied) is probably best.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why an instructor would call a language a "medium" rather than simply saying "this class will be taught in English".

Comment: @Catija: [American Sign Language is a medium for the hearing impaired.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JBPZ3wfYEF0C&pg=PA48&dq=%22sign+language+is+a+medium%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sign%20language%20is%20a%20medium%22&f=false) The usage is perfectly credible, and it's not really important whether you'd prefer something shorter on stylistic grounds. OP isn't asking for a general proofreading service - he just wants to know about the usage of ***of*** and ***for*** in the example context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure what ASL has to do with this. I was also assuming that the OP was **reading** this somewhere, not that he was composing it, which is why my comment was phrased the way it was. As a native speaker I find it very confusing, regardless of how "credible" it is.

Comment: @Catija: Check out the question title. It doesn't really matter whether OP composed the example or came across it - what's at issue is the use of the two prepositions. Which as I pointed out, could credibly be either reversed or both replaced by *either*. But in the final analysis, these are *stylistic* choices rather than a matter of established grammatical principles. And personally, I approve the actual choices in the example more than any obvious alternative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm allowed to make comments, as are you. We all have that privilege. If you feel my comment is inappropriate, flag it... There's no reason to add to the commentary a secondary discussion about whether a comment is appropriate or not.

Comment: @Catija: I don't feel there's anything "inappropriate" about the fact of you posting your first comment - I was simply pointing out that it's not really relevant to the question as posed. Which I probably wouldn't have done had your comment not already been given a couple of upvotes *and* there was a downvote for the question itself. To some extent I think this question might be better suited to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but that doesn't justify "criticising" it for reasons probably associated with the fact that the OP doesn't look like a native speaker.

Comment: @Catija The term "medium" does not refer to the language itself, but is short for "medium of instruction". In places where multiple languages are spoken e.g. Malaysia, they speak of *English-medium schools, Malay-medium schools, Tamil-medium schools, Chinese-medium schools* etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to consider the basal sentence, wnich is "The medium ... is English." This is clear and correct. The qualifying text "of instruction for the entire course" does not affect this correctness.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to prepositions, it's not a matter of grammatically correct but if the meaning is being conveyed in a way that is acceptable to native speakers of English.  "Of" indicates the relationship that you want.  In other languages, different prepositions would be used and if you translate that back into English it might be grammatically correct but the meaning would be unclear.  Learning which preposition to use is a matter of memorization based on the meaning you want to convey.  We say "I saw him on TV last night," but when you think about it, you actually saw him "in the TV."